# The formal name (or correct term) of a plane bounded by 4 segments

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

We can define a plane with:

$$ax + by + cz + d = 0$$

However we assume all the variables above are $\in \mathbb{R}$.

Is there a formal name for a plane that is bounded by four line segments, or bounded to some finite area?

This may be analogous to when we differentiate a `line` from a `segment`, however I'm not sure if a term exists or if we would just call them a "square" or "rectangle" that happen to be in a 3D coordinate system.

Or is my definition wrong and a plane also includes a bounded area?

Comment: You are talking about a [trimmed surface](http://docs.mcneel.com/rhino/5/help/en-us/seealso/sak_splittrim.htm)

Comment: Yes: quadrilateral. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateral

Comment: a bounded surface with curvature equal to zero?

Comment: 'Quadrilateral' is an appropriate name, and it does not depend  on the way you describe the plane which contains the figure.

Comment: [Polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon), or $4$-gon.

Comment: @CiaPan - would a non-planar four edged shape also be a quadrilateral?

Comment: @ja72 In a spherical geometry an area delimited with three geodesics is called a 'spherical triangle', so I suppose a similary defined four-edge region would be a 'spherical quadrilateral'. And probably same in other non-flat spaces.